# ASP.NET MVC Multiple Forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm still a beginner at .NET MVC, so please correct me if I'm doing something silly. I'm trying to create an action/view combination that will allow me to display 2 edit forms from 1 linq query. So here's my action:

```
Function Settings() As ActionResult
    Dim pagetext = (From t In _db.PageTexts _
                    Where t.campus = My.Resources.Campus _
                    Select t)
    Return View(pagetext)
End Function
```

And here is my view:

```
<% For Each item As EDKiosk.PageText In Model%> 
<% Using Html.BeginForm("Settings", "Admin")%>
    <div class="editor-label">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(Function(model) item.recommend)%>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%= Html.TextAreaFor(Function(model) item.recommend)%>
        <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) item.recommend)%>
    </div>
<% End Using %>
<% Next %>
```

So, my first question is, am I doing that right? Then, my follow-up question is how would my  method handle this data? Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

Per Samuel's suggestion, I reworked my code like this-

```
<% Dim hidden = New With {Key .type = "hidden"}%>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%= Html.TextBox("id", item.id.ToString(), hidden)%>
</div>

<div class="editor-field">
    <%= Html.Label("recommend")%>
    <%= Html.TextArea("welcome", item.recommend.ToString())%>
</div>
```

It works now, but I feel like its still kind of clunky. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating forms with a single form element, `recommend`.  You probably need a hidden form field for an associated ID or include the ID in the form action route data.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML you can have as much forms as you like, you just have to make sure that they are never nested as this would result in an undefined behavior among browsers. In your particular case you generate a form for each element in your model but this form doesn't contain any input field (hidden, text, dropdownlist, checkbox, radio button, ...). So if you submit an empty form no data will be sent to the controller action and you won't be able to identify which one was submitted. So you might want to include some information as input field such as an unique ID field which would allow you to fetch the corresponding model and perform some operations on it.